# Auto-selecting a dropdown option at WooCommerce checkout based on a session variable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, session-variables, checkout

I have been trying to save a parameter from my url `example.com/?lc=Business1` to a session, and then use this variable to auto-select from a list at checkout in woocommerce.

The dropdown always displays "None" at the moment.

This is my code:

```php
//Start Session
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}

function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}



//* Write url parameter to session variable lc
if (isset($_GET['lc'])) {
    $_SESSION['lc'] = $_GET['lc'];
}


//* Add Local C drop-down to checkout
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'local_c_add_checkout');
function local_c_add_checkout( $checkout ) {
    $data = WC()->session->get('lc');

    woocommerce_form_field( 'C_form', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array( 'drop-champ' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Local C' ),
        'default'       => 'lc',
        'options'       => array(
            'blank'     => __( 'None' ),
            'Business1' => __( 'Business 1' ),
            'Business2' => __( 'Business 2')
        )
        
 ),

    $checkout->get_value( 'C_form' ));
    
}
```

---

I'm sure there is something I am doing wrong/overlooking? and would appreciate guidance as to how to get my code to work.